# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted

Tags: sql-server, triggers

```
ALTER TRIGGER t1
ON dbo.Customers

FOR INSERT
AS

BEGIN TRANSACTION

/* variables */

DECLARE
    @maxid bigint

SELECT @customerid = id FROM inserted

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.new_table ON

DECLARE
    @maxid bigint

SELECT @maxid = MAX(ID) FROM new_table

INSERT INTO new_table (ID, ParentID, Foo, Bar, Buzz)
    SELECT ID+@maxid, ParentID+@maxid, Foo, Bar, Buzz FROM initial_table

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.new_tableOFF

/* execute */
COMMIT TRANSACTION

GO
```

fails with:

> SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted
>   when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is
>   used as an expression

How to fix it?

What I am trying to do is

- insert `id` and `parentid`, each INCREASED by `@maxid`
- from `initial_table`
- into `new_table`

thnx

**new_table**

```
id (bigint) 
parentid (bigint - linked to id) 
foo | bar | buzz (others are nvarchar, not really important)
```

**initial table**

```
id (bigint) 
parentid (bigint - linked to id)
foo | bar | buzz (others are nvarchar, not really important)
```

Comment: what is @fizz doing in this statement? `INSERT INTO new_table (ID, ParentID, Foo, Bar, @fizz, Buzz)`, i think that should be 
`INSERT INTO new_table (ID, ParentID, Foo, Bar, fizz, Buzz)
    SELECT ID+@maxid, ParentID+@maxid, Foo, Bar,@fizz, Buzz FROM initial_table`

Comment: ignore @fizz :P just another variable with a static value :P

Comment: `@fizz` on `INSERT INTO new_table (ID, ParentID, Foo, Bar, @fizz, Buzz)`. isn't it suppose to be column name?

Comment: check if there are any triggers defined on the table you are inserting data?

Comment: by THAT table you mean which one exactly?

Comment: Why is this tagged w/ triggers? Is there code we are not seeing here?

Comment: yes, alter trigger, etc... i removed it because i thought it was not needed really...

Comment: Give us the complete picture if possible. I dont see a subquery in your current question.

Comment: check this - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1a4a/1, it should work, there is something missing from your question

Comment: Can you give us schema of tables. because i try [it without error here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/931bf/2)

Comment: the problem is def in +@maxid because this works > INSERT INTO new_table (ID, ParentID, Foo, Bar, Buzz)
    SELECT ID+@maxid, ParentID+@maxid, Foo, Bar, Buzz FROM initial_table. WELL NOT WORKS, FAILS BECAUSE THE id conflicts, which is why i am trying to add MAXID

Comment: also changed the line SELECT @maxid = MAX(ID) FROM new_table - it used to be another_table, this was incorrect. as it is now in the OP it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are battling against a few errors I suspect.

1.
You are inserting values that violate a unique constraint in new_table.
Avoid the existence error by joining against the table you are inserting into. Adjust the join condition to match your table's constraint:

```
insert into new_table (ID, ParentID, Foo, Bar, Buzz)
    select  ID+@maxid, ParentID+@maxid, Foo, Bar, Buzz 
    from    initial_table i
    left
    join    new_table N on 
            i.ID+@maxid = n.ID or 
            i.ParentID+@maxid = n.ParentId
    where   n.ID is null --make sure its not already there
```

2.
Somewhere, a subquery has returned multiple rows where you expect one.
The subquery error is either in the code that inserts into dbo.Customer (triggering t1), or perhaps in a trigger defined on new_table.  I do not see anything in the posted code that would throw the subquery exception.

Triggers (aka, landmines) inserting into tables that have triggers defined on them is a recipe for pain. If possible, try to refactor some of this logic out of triggers and into code you can logically follow.

Comment: i do have a trigger on new new_table, on insert it adds into another table. not sure why that would fail because of it?

Comment: actually i disabled it (that other trigger) and now this sql from the question works. so i'll have to check the other trigger then. thnx

Comment: this is hard fixing this in a question and answer form :(

Answer (score 2):

First you have to assume there will be more than one record in inserted or deleted. You should not ever set a value in inserted or deleted table to a scalar varaible in a SQL server trigger. It will cause a problem if the insert includes more than one record and sooner or later it will.

Next you should not ever consider setting identity insert on in a trigger. What were you thinking? If you have an identity field then use that, don't then try to manually create a value.

Next the subquery issue is associated apparently with the other trigger where you are also assuming only one record at a time would be processed. I would suspect that you will need to examine every trigger in your database and fix this basic problem.

Now when you run this part of the code:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (ID, ParentID, Foo, Bar, Buzz) 
SELECT ID+@maxid, ParentID+@maxid, Foo, Bar, Buzz FROM initial_table
```

You are trying to insert all records in the table not just the ones in inserted. So since your trigger on the other table is incorreclty written, you are hitting an error which is actually hiding the error you will get when you try to insert 2000 records with the same PK into the new table or worse if you don't have a PK, it will happily insert them all every time you insert one record.

Answer (score 1):

You have a trigger containing the statement:

```
SELECT @customerid = id FROM inserted
```

The `inserted` table contains a row for each row that was inserted (or updated for `UPDATE` triggers).  A statement executed that inserted more than one row, the trigger fired, and your assumption was exposed.

Recode the trigger to operate on rowsets, not a single row.

Answer (score -1):

while using a sub query in d any kind of select, try to tune your query so that the sub query only returns 1 value and not multiple.

If multiple are needed then restructure the query in such a way that the table becomes part of main query.

I am giving example of SQL:

```
Select col1, (select col2 from table2 where table2.col3=table1.col4) from table1;
```

If col2 returns multiple rows then the query fails then re-write it to:

```
Select col1, col2 from table1,table2 where table2.col3=table1.col4;
```

I hope you get the point.

Comment: yes it is what you are saying, but i am not sure how to restructure the query. the select does return multiple values.

Answer (score -3):

You shouldn't SELECT it, you should SET it.

```
SET @maxid = MAX(ID) FROM another_table
```

Comment: no. it works as written. the problem seems to be with SELECT ID+@maxid, ParentID+@maxid